# How can I replace ?? with ternary operator in js?

Tags: javascript, python, replace, browserify

I have a JS file which was created using browserify, and it uses the `??` operator. The problem is, the environment where I am executing this JS file doesn't support that operator yet.

Is there any way I can go through the file, search and replace it using regex?

The change would be from this:

```js
object.error ?? 0
```

To this:

```js
x == undefined ? 0 : object.error
```

Comment: "How to replace text" is potentially more of a software usage question, rather than a programming one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it JS or Python?

Anyway, try capturing the line with:

```
(([^ \t]+)[ \t]*\?\?[ \t]*\d+)
```

This expression returns two groups:

1. The line to be replaced
2. The `object.error`

You then need to replace group#1 by `x == undefined ? 0 : group#2`